# How to write all ASCII characters in Swift String

Tags: swift, string, ascii

Trying to find the shortest / most compact way to write out ASCII characters in Swift into a single string. For example, in JavaScript you can do `'\x00'` for the decimal equivalent of 0 in ASCII, or you can write `'\0`, which is 2 characters shorter. So if you have a lot of these characters, that is 2x smaller file size.

Wondering how to write the ASCII characters 0-31 and 127 in Swift so they are minimal, into a single string. In JavaScript, that sort of looks like this:

```
'\0...\33abcdef...\127¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½...'
```

Comment: I'm looking for how to write 1 string with every ASCII character in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you would use `\u{x}` where `x` is the hex value. In your case `\u{0}` through `\u{1f}` and `\u{7f}`.

As in C based languages, Swift strings also supports `\0` for "null", `\t` for "tab", `\n` for "newline", and `\r` for "carriage return". Unlike C, Swift does not support `\b` or `\f`.

If you want to create single `String` will all 128 ASCII characters then you can do:

```
let ascii = String(Array(0...127).map { Character(Unicode.Scalar($0)) })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of these characters, maybe put them in a Data object and then convert it to a string:

```
let data = Data(bytes: Array(0...31) + [127])
let text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Based on your comment, you could do:

```
let tab = Data(bytes: [9])
let null = Data(bytes: [0])

let data = "abc".data(using: .utf8)! + tab + null + "morechars".data(using: .utf8)! + tab
```

Comment: Interesting, wait not sure I understand. So I want to hardcode the bytes into the file, so like `let data = "abcdef\t\n..."` along with the rest of the ASCII characters. Not sure if you're saying I can represent them in decimal notation like that, with `let data = 0` meaning `\0` NULL character, and `9` meaning the TAB character. That would be cool! Then it could just be `let data = Data(bytes: ["abc", 9 /* tab */, 0 /* null */, "morechars", 9 /* another tab */ , ... ])`. Let me know if that's what you're saying. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you want to save bytes to a file! Don't use a string at all. Use a Data object